# Limit access to MWAA Public Environment UI - Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I set up a public mwaa environment but i want to limit UI access to only specific IP range

I tried removing everything from the inbound security group that mwaa public environment is using but it is still accessible from the public internet, removing it also caused scheduler to crash but i added 5432 port and it is fixed,

That is the only inbound rule that the environment has yet UI is still accessible

I am probably missing sth but not sure what

Is it possible to limit access to UI ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the MWAA cluster in a VPC, then setup the ACL rules to deny the traffic coming from the public network, and accept only the traffic cumming from your IP: [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/vpc-security.html)

| Rule number | Type | Protocol | Port range | Source | Allow/Deny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | All IPv4 traffic | All | All | <your IP> | Allow |
| * | All IPv4 traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Deny |